# fwrite with BMP file returning 0 and segmentation fault

Tags: fwrite, bmp

I'm trying to read a simple bmp file then invert the color then save it back to the file system using fread and fwrite binary mode.

So I did

```
BMP_Image * img; 
BMP_Header * hdr;

fread(hdr,sizeof(BMP_Header),1, fptr); 

img->width = hdr->width;
img->height = hdr->height;
img->bytes_per_pixel = hdr->bits*BIT_TO_BYTE; 
img->header = *hdr;
img->data_size = hdr->size;
```

to get the header information where BMP_Header is a struct

Then read the image data and put into array

```
fread(data, sizeof(char), img->data_size - 54, fptr);
```

Then I subtract each element in my image data by 255

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0;i<img->data_size;i++){
   data[i] = 255 - data[i];
}
```

Now when I want to write the file back to the file system, I couldn't get it to work properly. I know you'd have to do fwrite 2 times. First writing the header, then writing the image data.

I have so far:

```
 fwrite(header, 1 ,dataSize, fptr_out);
```

which gives me sgmentation fault and 0 byte bmp file.

Here are the typedefs of my BMP_Header and BMP_image struct

```
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef int int32_t;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t type;                      // Magic identifier
    uint32_t size;                      // File size in bytes
    uint16_t reserved1;     // Not used
    uint16_t reserved2;       // Not used
    uint32_t offset;                    // Offset to image data in bytes
    uint32_t header_size;               // Header size in bytes
    int32_t  width;                     // Width of the image
    int32_t  height;                    // Height of image
    uint16_t planes;                    // Number of color planes
    uint16_t bits;                      // Bits per pixel
    uint32_t compression;               // Compression type
    uint32_t imagesize;                 // Image size in bytes
    int32_t  xresolution;               // Pixels per meter
    int32_t  yresolution;               // Pixels per meter
    uint32_t ncolours;                  // Number of colors  
    uint32_t importantcolours;          // Important colors

} BMP_Header;

typedef struct {
    BMP_Header header;
    int data_size;
    int width;
    int height;
    int bytes_per_pixel; // This amount should be equals to number of bits/8
    char *data;
} BMP_Image;
```

Comment: ...did you initialize `BMP_Header *hdr` at all? Please post your real code!!

Comment: You can tell its not the real code because there are missing semicolons.

Comment: The real code is really long and has multiple files